# Error in the Javascript Jquery code

Tags: javascript, json

There is an error showing on this code, I have looked through it for hours and cannot find it, could anyone assist please

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#show-records').click(function () {
       $.post('./includes/processes.php', function (data) {
           var pushedData = jQuery.parseJSON - (DATA);
           var htmldata = " ";
           $.each(pushedData, function (i, serverData) {
               htmldata = htmldata, +'- ' + serverData.Style + ', ' + serverData.Brand + ', ' + serverData.Model + ', ' + serverData.January Registrations + ', ' + serverData.February Registrations + ', ' + serverData.March Registrations + '<br>';
               $('#show-list').html(htmldata);
           });
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: there isnt an error message, have writing this in dreamweaver and its showing the red syntax error label, also when i execute the code it does nothing now, its indicating line 10 where htmldata = htmldata is

Answer (score 0):

> htmldata = htmldata, + '

is invalid syntax, try

> htmldata = htmldata + '

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma after html data on that line. When appending to variables you should try and use this syntax too, enclosing all other strings in "string" .

Change that line of code to:

```
htmldata += ', - ' + serverDat...
```

The `+=` is the same as writing `htmldata = htmldata + ', -' + ..` which is easier to read and maintain.